# jQuery animated (with transition plugin for hardware acceleration) is crashing the page on iPad browsers

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, animation, hardware-acceleration

http://www.djdenner.ca/index_new

Is this simply an issue of too much going on a page for an iPad (iPad 4th gen with retina display)

When I open the page, half the time it crashes.

I've taken steps to reduce the number of animations, the number of mathematical calculations etc. but it still does the same thing.

I was using animate, fadeIn & fadeOut for most of it. I started switching it with the transit plug-in to leverage hardware acceleration wherever possible but it still crashes the ipad.

Works really well on desktop browsers though.

JS Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    window.animationstage = 0;
    setTimeout("index_window_resize()",500);

    load_1();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        alert('resize bind action');
        index_window_resize();
    });

    $(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
        alert('orientation bind action');
        index_window_resize();
    });

    $('.index_menu_container').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_1').stop().fadeTo(300, 1.0);
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_2').stop().fadeTo(300, 0.9);
                return false;
            }, 
            function(){
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_1').stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_2').stop().fadeTo(300, 0.5);
                return false;
            }
        );
    });


    $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
        $(this).off('hover');
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location = link;
    });

    $('.index_menu_container').on('click touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
        $(this).off('hover');
    });

});


function load_1() {
    window.animationstage = 1;
    index_window_resize();
    $('#logo_large').delay(500).transition({opacity: 1},3000);
    $('#logo_large_shine').delay(2500).transition({opacity: 1},1000).delay(300).fadeTo(1000, 0.0, function(){
        if(window.windoww>=768) {
            load_2(); // trigger phase 2 of animation
        } else {
            //alert(window.windoww);
            $('#logo_large').fadeTo(1000,0.0, function(){
                window.location = "http://www.djdenner.ca/listings";
            });
        }
    // after animation stuff is done... prepare the menu DIVs
    });
    $('#logo_shine_silver').delay(2800).transition({opacity: 0},1000);


}   

function load_2() {
    window.animationstage = 2;
    // by now logo must have loaded... run the index_misc_images_preload loading mechanism
    $.ajax({
        url: "/images_preload.php",
    }).done(function ( data ) {
        $('#index_misc_images_preload').html(data);
    });


    $('#logo_large_shine').remove();
    // calculate logo width
    var logotopw = 460; // default width
    var logotoph = 113; // default height
    var top_leather_top = 160;
    var logo_large_top = 30;
    if(window.windoww<520) {
        var logoratio = logotoph/logotopw;
        logotopw = window.logow;
        logotoph = window.logoh;
        top_leather_top = logotoph+25;
        logo_large_top = 10;
        $('#top_logo_shadow').hide();
    }
    $('#index_contact_info').delay(1000).transition({opacity: 0},1000);
    $('#logo_large').delay(500).transition({width:logotopw+'px', height:logotoph+'px', marginTop:logo_large_top+'px'},2000);
    $('#top_leather').delay(1000).transition({top:'0px', height:top_leather_top+'px'}, 2000,'easeOutQuint', function(){
        load_3();
    });
}

function load_3() {
    window.animationstage = 3;
    // position slideshow #index_slideshow_container
    index_window_resize(); // run this again just so the width & height of the slideshow etc. is set right. 

    $('#index_menu').slideDown(600);
    $('#index_slideshow_container').fadeTo(1000,1.0);
        $('#index_slideshow_container div:eq(0)').fadeTo(1000,1.0, function(){
            load_4();
        }); // load up first one by default.
}

function load_4() { 
    window.animationstage = 4;
    index_window_resize();
}

function index_window_resize() {
    // find 60% mark from top
    window.windowh = $(window).height();
    window.windoww = $(window).width();

    //alert(window.windoww+' X '+window.windowh);

    $('#full_container').height(window.windowh);

    window.logow = $('#logo_large').width();
    window.logoh = $('#logo_large').height();

    window.ratiow = window.logow/940;
    window.ratioh = window.logoh/232;

    window.top50 = window.windowh*0.5-(window.logoh/2);

    window.logoleft = window.windowh-940;

    if(window.animationstage<2) {
        // if the animation stage is below 2, then we adjust the top margin of the large logo. 
        // if it's after that, that's after the logos' been moved to the top so we skip it. 
        $('#logo_large').css({"margin-top": window.top50+'px'});
    }

    // now deal with the shine.. it's 173 X 173 wide by default, unless on mobile. Need to use percentage. 
    var shineposleft = 785; // relative position default
    var shinepostop = 17; // relative position default

    shineposleft = window.ratiow * shineposleft;
    shinepostop = window.ratioh * shinepostop;

    var shinesize = ratiow * 173;

    $('#logo_large_shine').css({"width": shinesize+'px', "height" : shinesize+'px', "top":'-'+shinepostop+'px', "left":shineposleft+'px' });

    // adjust the width & height of the logo on top. 
    if(window.animationstage>2) {
        if(window.windoww<520 && window.windoww<window.windowh) {
            // smaller screen.. adjust width of logo to 80% of the window. 
            $('#logo_large').width(window.windoww*0.8).height(window.windoww*0.8*232/940).css({"marginTop":'15px'});
            var top_leather_h = $('#logo_large').height()+25;
            var index_menuw = window.windoww*0.8;
            $('#top_leather').height(top_leather_h);
            $('#top_logo_shadow').hide();
            $('#index_menu').css({"width":index_menuw+'px', "marginTop" : 10});

            var menu_containerratio = 60/400;
            $('.index_menu_container').css({"width":index_menuw+'px', "height":(menu_containerratio*index_menuw)+'px'});

            // if the ratio of the width/height is less than the 2400 X 1140, then img should be 100% height. 
            index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();
            $('#index_slideshow_base img').css({'width':'auto', 'height':'100%'});

        } else if(window.windoww<768) {

            // smaller screen.. adjust width of logo to 80% of the window. 
            $('#logo_large').width(window.windoww*0.4).height(window.windoww*0.4*232/940).css({"marginTop":'15px'});
            var top_leather_h = $('#logo_large').height()+25;
            $('#top_leather').height(top_leather_h);
            $('#top_logo_shadow').hide();
            $('#index_menu').css({"width":window.windoww*0.4, "marginTop" : $('#logo_large').height()*0.3});

            var menu_containerratio = 60/400;
            $('.index_menu_container').css({"width":window.windoww*0.4, "height":menu_containerratio*window.windoww*0.4});

            // if the ratio of the width/height is less than the 2400 X 1140, then img should be 100% height. 
            index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();
            $('#index_slideshow_base img').css({'width':'auto', 'height':'100%'});

        } else {
            // full screen
            $('#logo_large').css({"marginTop":'30px', 'width':'460px', 'height':'113px'});
            $('#top_leather').height(160);
            $('#top_logo_shadow').show();
            $('#index_menu').css({"width":'400px', "marginTop" : '80px'});
            $('.index_menu_container').css({"width":'400px', "height":'60px'});

            // see if the screen ratio is vertical or horizontal...
            // ratio is 2400 X 1140
            var index_slideshow_container_ratio = 1140/2400;

            // after leather bar & top logo has been adjusted.. slideshow height adjuster

            var index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();

            if (index_slideshow_container_height/window.windoww>index_slideshow_container_ratio) {
                // if the ratio of the width/height is less than the 2400 X 1140, then img should be 100% height. 
                index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();

                var index_slide_imgh = index_slideshow_container_height;
                var index_slide_imgw = index_slide_imgh/1140*2400;
                var index_slide_left = (index_slide_imgw-window.windoww)/2;
                var index_slide_top = 0;
            } else {

                // image is more panoramic (wider) than provided space compared to the height. set height as base. 
                var index_slide_imgw = window.windoww;
                var index_slide_imgh = index_slide_imgw/2400*1140;
                var index_slide_top = 0; // regardless of how tall the image is, start at top so we dont cut heads off.
                var index_slide_left = 0;
            }

            $('#index_slideshow_container').width(window.windoww).height(index_slideshow_container_height).css('top', $('#top_leather').height()+'px');
            $('.index_slide').width(window.windoww).height(index_slideshow_container_height);

            $('.index_slideshow_bg').css({width:index_slide_imgw+'px', height:index_slide_imgh+'px', left:-index_slide_left+'px', top:-index_slide_top+'px'}); 

        }

        // index_slide elements are set.. now to configure the width/height of the image within so as to not break ratio
        // 2400/1140 is the ratio of the images. 
        var index_slide_img_ratio = 2400/1140;
        var index_slide_ratio = window.windoww/index_slideshow_container_height;

        if(index_slide_img_ratio<=index_slide_ratio) {

        } else {
            // image is more portrait (taller) than provided space compared to the width. set width as base. 

        }
    }

    if(window.animationstage>3) {
        var index_slideshoww = ((index_slide_imgw-400)/2)*0.6; // from full width, deduct the menubar width (400), split in half.. then 60% of remaining gap on left. 
        $('.index_slideshow').width(index_slideshoww); // set the width first. 

        $('.index_slideshow').each(function(){
            var index_slideshowh = $(this).find('p').height(); // set height of each item based on the paragraph height + 60 pixels gap
            $(this).height(index_slideshowh);
            $(this).css({'opacity':0, 'left':'30px', 'top':(index_slideshow_container_height-index_slideshowh-120)+'px'});
            // for some reason 30px from bottom doesn't work, presumably because it's before the fathering DIV loads and registers height at 0px at the moment of running.
            // So we set margin from top. Deduct the height of the element from total height and then another 120 pixels for gaps etc. to get final margin from top.

        });
    }


}

$(function() {

    var degree = 0,
        timer;

    function rotate() {    
        $('#logo_large_shine').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        // timeout increase degrees:
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree;
            rotate(); // loop it
        },20);
    }

    rotate();    // run it!

});
```

The HTML DOM:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>West Vancouver's Fine Homes & Luxury Real Estate - D.J.Denner Real Estate</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/css/skeleton.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.djdenner.ca/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/css/common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/css/common_mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.djdenner.ca/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.djdenner.ca/css/layout.css?hash=206" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.djdenner.ca/css/fancybox_iframe.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.djdenner.ca/css/index_new.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.djdenner.ca/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.djdenner.ca/js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/hash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.djdenner.ca/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/jquery.timer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/js/iepngfix_tilebg.js"></script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>




                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.djdenner.ca/js/index_new.js?rand=706"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.djdenner.ca/js/index_slides_new.js?rand=353"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function tfSeFQsfNMcdzdK()
{
/* Munged addy code - YOU CAN EDIT COMMENT THIS TAG BETWEEN THE TWO STARS */ 
var jfobOhWAXphYDrY=["x64","106","x40","x64","106","100","x65","110","110","101","x72","46","x63","97"];
var IAucJqkicTDjNlW=['?','s','u','b','j','e','c','t','=','&','c','c','=','&','b','c','c','=','&','b','o','d','y','='];
var hFcurDruaXqPhsD=["100","106","64","x64","x6a","x64","101","x6e","x6e","x65","114","x2e","x63","x61"];
document.write("<a href=\"&#x6d;&#97;&#000105;&#000108;&#x74;&#000111;&#58;");
for (i=0; i<jfobOhWAXphYDrY.length; i++) document.write('&#'+jfobOhWAXphYDrY[i]+';');
for (i=0; i<IAucJqkicTDjNlW.length; i++) document.write(IAucJqkicTDjNlW[i]);
document.write('" style="" class="" id="">');
for (i=0; i<hFcurDruaXqPhsD.length; i++) document.write('&#'+hFcurDruaXqPhsD[i]+';');
document.write('</a>');
/* Munged addy code - YOU CAN EDIT COMMENT THIS TAG BETWEEN THE TWO STARS */
}
</script>




</head>


<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



<div id="full_container"><!-- opening for homepage -->
<div id="index_slideshow_container">
    <div class="index_slide" id="index_slideshow_base">
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_slideshow_base.jpg" class="index_slideshow_bg" />

        <div class="index_slideshow light_smokescreen" id="index_slideshow_0">
                        <p>Properties short intro that will show on index page. Edit under Pages -> Properties for Sale -> Short Excerpt field below content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="index_slideshow light_smokescreen" id="index_slideshow_1">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat bibendum commodo. Aliquam ultricies, quam id faucibus tempus, eros lorem tempor augue, ultricies tempor justo mauris sit amet enim. Nulla tellus lectus, feugiat et nisi aliquam, adipiscing accumsan lacus. Proin varius venenatis volutpat. Phasellus elit tellus, pulvinar sit amet adipiscing non, fermentum vel nisi. Vestibulum sed tellus sem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="index_slideshow light_smokescreen" id="index_slideshow_2">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat bibendum commodo. Aliquam ultricies, quam id faucibus tempus, eros lorem tempor augue, ultricies tempor justo mauris sit amet enim. Nulla tellus lectus, feugiat et nisi aliquam, adipiscing accumsan lacus. Proin varius venenatis volutpat. Phasellus elit tellus, pulvinar sit amet adipiscing non, fermentum vel nisi. Vestibulum sed tellus sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat bibendum commodo. Aliquam ultricies, quam id faucibus tempus, eros lorem tempor augue, ultricies tempor justo mauris sit amet enim. Nulla tellus lectus, feugiat et nisi aliquam, adipiscing accumsan lacus. Proin varius venenatis volutpat. Phasellus elit tellus, pulvinar sit amet adipiscing non, fermentum vel nisi. Vestibulum sed tellus sem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="index_slideshow light_smokescreen" id="index_slideshow_3">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In volutpat bibendum commodo. Aliquam ultricies, quam id faucibus tempus, eros lorem tempor augue, ultricies tempor justo mauris sit amet enim. Nulla tellus lectus, feugiat et nisi aliquam, adipiscing accumsan lacus. Proin varius venenatis volutpat. Phasellus elit tellus, pulvinar sit amet adipiscing non, fermentum vel nisi. Vestibulum sed tellus sem.</p>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>


<div id="top_leather">
    <div id="top_logo_shadow">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="logo_large">
    <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/logo_large.png" id="logo_large_image" />
    <div id="logo_large_shine">
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/shine_gold.png" id="logo_shine_gold" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/shine_silver.png" id="logo_shine_silver" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="index_menu">
    <div id="index_menu_0" class="index_menu_container">
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_0.png" class="index_menu_bg_0" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_1.png" class="index_menu_bg_1" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_0.png" class="index_menu_bg_2" />
        <a href="http://www.djdenner.ca/listings"><img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/blank.gif" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="index_menu_1" class="index_menu_container">
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_0.png" class="index_menu_bg_0" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_1.png" class="index_menu_bg_1" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_1.png" class="index_menu_bg_2" />
        <a href="http://www.djdenner.ca/marketing"><img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/blank.gif" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="index_menu_2" class="index_menu_container">
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_0.png" class="index_menu_bg_0" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_1.png" class="index_menu_bg_1" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_2.png" class="index_menu_bg_2" />
        <a href="http://www.djdenner.ca/community"><img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/blank.gif" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="index_menu_3" class="index_menu_container">
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_0.png" class="index_menu_bg_0" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_bg_1.png" class="index_menu_bg_1" />
        <img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/index_menu_3.png" class="index_menu_bg_2" />
        <a href="http://www.djdenner.ca/meet-dj"><img src="http://www.djdenner.ca/images/blank.gif" width="100%" height="100%" /></a>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="index_contact_info">
    <p><a href="http://www.djdenner.ca/meet-dj">Skip Intro</a></p>
</div>





<div id="index_misc_images_preload">

</div>




</div>
```

Comment: Works fine on iPhone4, so it shouldn't be a resource issue (except if you render different code for iPhone). I would suggest you to use web inspector to find out what's going on on your iPad: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

Comment: What browser are you using on your ipad

Comment: Have you tried using
http://jquerymobile.com/download/
its for mobile

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's the php script (**images_preload.php**) that you are calling  that is screwing things up.

On my iPad, if I browse your site I get the behaviour you describe: the animation is really slow, and it crashes about half of the times.

On the other hand, if I host the html and js on a test server it seems to be working fine:
[Test site](http://dennercatest.appspot.com)

The only real difference beetween the official site and mine (at least where the client is involved) is that this script does not get called.

And, monitoring network traffic when loading your site, after calling the php script there is a barrage of network requests, going from 50 to 175, and most of those are image GETs.

It could be that the iPad cannot handle that much traffic, while performing animations at the same time.

My suggestion would be first to comment out the image preload, and check that the animation is now smooth and the iPad doesn't crash, and then you will have to find a way to optimise the script.

Comment: I tried that already actually. Still no difference, crashed regardless, but I'll give it another shot just in case.

Comment: Ok. It seems to be working much better now, what was the problem ?

Comment: I removed animation queues. I'm shocked to see that the ipad has trouble handling this much animation. We live in the world of 1080p graphics now. Now the inner pages, which used to be fine, are crashing my ipad... http://www.djdenner.ca/showlisting/1/-4112-Burkehill-Road-Bayridge-West-Vancouver-vancouver-realtor

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not error free but I don't see any reason for IPad to crash, I have run it with my Chrome and Opera browser on Sony Xperia ZR and did everything fine, I don't have an IPhone or Ipad to test it but you can try load jsfiddle.net/m/ege trough your IPad and then debug it with desktop using debug.phonegap.com/client/#jsf_ege however I found some errors and cleared it, in the hope it may help, try use this and see what will happen?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.animationstage = 0;
    setTimeout(index_window_resize(),500);

    load_1();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        index_window_resize();
    });

    $(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
        index_window_resize();
    });

    $('.index_menu_container').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_1').stop().fadeTo(300, 1.0);
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_2').stop().fadeTo(300, 0.9);
                return false;
            }, 
            function(){
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_1').stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
                $(this).children('.index_menu_bg_2').stop().fadeTo(300, 0.5);
                return false;
            }
        );
    });


    $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
        $(this).off('hover');
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location = link;
    });

    $('.index_menu_container').on('click touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
        $(this).off('hover');
    });

});


function load_1() {
    window.animationstage = 1;
    index_window_resize();
    $('#logo_large').delay(500).transition({opacity: 1},3000);
    $('#logo_large_shine').delay(2500).transition({opacity: 1},1000).delay(300).fadeTo(1000, 0.0, function(){
        if(window.windoww>=768) {
            load_2(); // trigger phase 2 of animation
        } else {
            //alert(window.windoww);
            $('#logo_large').fadeTo(1000,0.0, function(){
                window.location = "http://www.djdenner.ca/listings";
            });
        }
    // after animation stuff is done... prepare the menu DIVs
    });
    $('#logo_shine_silver').delay(2800).transition({opacity: 0},1000);


}   

function load_2() {
    window.animationstage = 2;
    // by now logo must have loaded... run the index_misc_images_preload loading mechanism
    $.ajax({
        url: "/images_preload.php"
    }).done(function ( data ) {
        $('#index_misc_images_preload').html(data);
    });


    $('#logo_large_shine').remove();
    // calculate logo width
    var logotopw = 460; // default width
    var logotoph = 113; // default height
    var top_leather_top = 160;
    var logo_large_top = 30;
    if(window.windoww<520) {
        var logoratio = logotoph/logotopw;
        logotopw = window.logow;
        logotoph = window.logoh;
        top_leather_top = logotoph+25;
        logo_large_top = 10;
        $('#top_logo_shadow').hide();
    }
    $('#index_contact_info').delay(1000).transition({opacity: 0},1000);
    $('#logo_large').delay(500).transition({width:logotopw+'px', height:logotoph+'px', marginTop:logo_large_top+'px'},2000);
    $('#top_leather').delay(1000).transition({top:'0px', height:top_leather_top+'px'}, 2000,'easeOutQuint', function(){
        load_3();
    });
}

function load_3() {
    window.animationstage = 3;
    // position slideshow #index_slideshow_container
    index_window_resize(); // run this again just so the width & height of the slideshow etc. is set right. 

    $('#index_menu').slideDown(600);
    $('#index_slideshow_container').fadeTo(1000,1.0);
        $('#index_slideshow_container div:eq(0)').fadeTo(1000,1.0, function(){
            load_4();
        }); // load up first one by default.
}

function load_4() { 
    window.animationstage = 4;
    index_window_resize();
}

function index_window_resize() {
    // find 60% mark from top
    window.windowh = $(window).height();
    window.windoww = $(window).width();

    //alert(window.windoww+' X '+window.windowh);

    $('#full_container').height(window.windowh);

    window.logow = $('#logo_large').width();
    window.logoh = $('#logo_large').height();

    window.ratiow = window.logow/940;
    window.ratioh = window.logoh/232;

    window.top50 = window.windowh*0.5-(window.logoh/2);

    window.logoleft = window.windowh-940;

    if(window.animationstage<2) {
        // if the animation stage is below 2, then we adjust the top margin of the large logo. 
        // if it's after that, that's after the logos' been moved to the top so we skip it. 
        $('#logo_large').css({"margin-top": window.top50+'px'});
    }

    // now deal with the shine.. it's 173 X 173 wide by default, unless on mobile. Need to use percentage. 
    var shineposleft = 785; // relative position default
    var shinepostop = 17; // relative position default

    shineposleft = window.ratiow * shineposleft;
    shinepostop = window.ratioh * shinepostop;

    var shinesize = ratiow * 173;

    $('#logo_large_shine').css({"width": shinesize+'px', "height" : shinesize+'px', "top":'-'+shinepostop+'px', "left":shineposleft+'px' });

    // adjust the width & height of the logo on top. 
    if(window.animationstage>2) {
        if(window.windoww<520 && window.windoww<window.windowh) {
            // smaller screen.. adjust width of logo to 80% of the window. 
            $('#logo_large').width(window.windoww*0.8).height(window.windoww*0.8*232/940).css({"marginTop":'15px'});
            var top_leather_h = $('#logo_large').height()+25;
            var index_menuw = window.windoww*0.8;
            $('#top_leather').height(top_leather_h);
            $('#top_logo_shadow').hide();
            $('#index_menu').css({"width":index_menuw+'px', "marginTop" : 10});

            var menu_containerratio = 60/400;
            $('.index_menu_container').css({"width":index_menuw+'px', "height":(menu_containerratio*index_menuw)+'px'});

            // if the ratio of the width/height is less than the 2400 X 1140, then img should be 100% height. 
            index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();
            $('#index_slideshow_base img').css({'width':'auto', 'height':'100%'});

        } else if(window.windoww<768) {

            // smaller screen.. adjust width of logo to 80% of the window. 
            $('#logo_large').width(window.windoww*0.4).height(window.windoww*0.4*232/940).css({"marginTop":'15px'});
            var top_leather_h = $('#logo_large').height()+25;
            $('#top_leather').height(top_leather_h);
            $('#top_logo_shadow').hide();
            $('#index_menu').css({"width":window.windoww*0.4, "marginTop" : $('#logo_large').height()*0.3});

            var menu_containerratio = 60/400;
            $('.index_menu_container').css({"width":window.windoww*0.4, "height":menu_containerratio*window.windoww*0.4});

            // if the ratio of the width/height is less than the 2400 X 1140, then img should be 100% height. 
            index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();
            $('#index_slideshow_base img').css({'width':'auto', 'height':'100%'});

        } else {
            // full screen
            $('#logo_large').css({"marginTop":'30px', 'width':'460px', 'height':'113px'});
            $('#top_leather').height(160);
            $('#top_logo_shadow').show();
            $('#index_menu').css({"width":'400px', "marginTop" : '80px'});
            $('.index_menu_container').css({"width":'400px', "height":'60px'});

            // see if the screen ratio is vertical or horizontal...
            // ratio is 2400 X 1140
            var index_slideshow_container_ratio = 1140/2400;

            // after leather bar & top logo has been adjusted.. slideshow height adjuster

            var index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();

            if (index_slideshow_container_height/window.windoww>index_slideshow_container_ratio) {
                // if the ratio of the width/height is less than the 2400 X 1140, then img should be 100% height. 
                index_slideshow_container_height = window.windowh-$('#top_leather').height();

                var index_slide_imgh = index_slideshow_container_height;
                var index_slide_imgw = index_slide_imgh/1140*2400;
                var index_slide_left = (index_slide_imgw-window.windoww)/2;
                var index_slide_top = 0;
            } else {

                // image is more panoramic (wider) than provided space compared to the height. set height as base. 
                var index_slide_imgw = window.windoww;
                var index_slide_imgh = index_slide_imgw/2400*1140;
                var index_slide_top = 0; // regardless of how tall the image is, start at top so we dont cut heads off.
                var index_slide_left = 0;
            }

            $('#index_slideshow_container').width(window.windoww).height(index_slideshow_container_height).css('top', $('#top_leather').height()+'px');
            $('.index_slide').width(window.windoww).height(index_slideshow_container_height);

            $('.index_slideshow_bg').css({width:index_slide_imgw+'px', height:index_slide_imgh+'px', left:-index_slide_left+'px', top:-index_slide_top+'px'}); 

        }

        // index_slide elements are set.. now to configure the width/height of the image within so as to not break ratio
        // 2400/1140 is the ratio of the images. 
        var index_slide_img_ratio = 2400/1140;
        var index_slide_ratio = window.windoww/index_slideshow_container_height;
    }

    if(window.animationstage>3) {
        var index_slideshoww = ((index_slide_imgw-400)/2)*0.6; // from full width, deduct the menubar width (400), split in half.. then 60% of remaining gap on left. 
        $('.index_slideshow').width(index_slideshoww); // set the width first. 

        $('.index_slideshow').each(function(){
            var index_slideshowh = $(this).find('p').height(); // set height of each item based on the paragraph height + 60 pixels gap
            $(this).height(index_slideshowh);
            $(this).css({'opacity':0, 'left':'30px', 'top':(index_slideshow_container_height-index_slideshowh-120)+'px'});
            // for some reason 30px from bottom doesn't work, presumably because it's before the fathering DIV loads and registers height at 0px at the moment of running.
            // So we set margin from top. Deduct the height of the element from total height and then another 120 pixels for gaps etc. to get final margin from top.

        });
    }


}

$(function() {

    var degree = 0,
        timer;

    function rotate() {    
        $('#logo_large_shine').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        // timeout increase degrees:
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree;
            rotate(); // loop it
        },20);
    }

    rotate();    // run it!

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested you're website on: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/eN9AZI/http://www.djdenner.ca/index_new and I found out that when you load your homepage it generates **48 requests**. Look at the following image that shows the percentile of the requests.

[image]

I do believe that if we reduced the number of requests we could solve the problem and prevent it from crashing the browser on the iPad.

My recommendation to reduce the requests for your homepage are as follows:

1. Reduce the quality of the images (this can be done through photoshop) or from free tools online such as http://www.webresizer.com/resizer/ also you can use image sprites to reduce the total number of requests. Also see if you could cut the images in smaller pieces and use `background: repeat-x;` properties as an example.
2. Group all your css style sheets in one big master stylesheet. So there aren't as much request.
3. Try to see if you can minimize the use of jQuery and use css3 advanced properties to replicate you're effects instead.